# What is the difference between switch-to-next-buffer and next-buffer?

Tags: buffers, window

To go to the next/prev buffer I use the commands `next-buffer` / `prev-buffer`. This works well and is very comfortable.
But there are also two other commands `switch-to-next-buffer` / `switch-to-prev-buffer` that do same thing.
What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 4):

`next-buffer` is a wrapper around `switch-to-next-buffer`. Since `switch-to-next-buffer` takes a `WINDOW` argument (and doesn't have a default key binding), it's more suitable for programmatic use, whereas `next-buffer` is more suitable for interactive use. Of course nothing prevents you from using `switch-to-next-buffer` interactively.

Comment: You can call it interactively,but since it just has `interactive` as its interactive specification, I don't see how that can do anything different from calling `next-buffer`

Comment: True. I'll amend my answer.